# How does php interpret the syntax $var[] = $val?

Tags: php, web-applications, syntax

I was looking through some inherited PHP code when I found the following:

```
$emails=array();
foreach($usrs as $usr){
    $emails[]=$usr['email'];
}
```

It's clear that this is trying to extract the 'email' property of each object in a list of users and hold them in an array.  That's what I want it to do.  Does this do that?  I've never seen such a thing work this way.  I replaced it with

```
array_push($emails, $usr['email']);
```

since I know that that does what I intend it to.

Comment: This is identical to `array_push`, but is less typing. You shouldn't replace it with `array_push`, but rather get used to using it.

Comment: Here's the docs: http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two are the same, almost.

It will add an item to the end of the array, just as `array_push` does. The only difference is `array_push` returns the new number of elements in the array. The empty bracket notation does not return anything, obviously.

You should get comfortable with this notation, it's easier to type and read.

[`array_push` on PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) mentions the use of this notation and covers two other differences as well.

> Note: If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function.
>
> Note: array_push() will raise a warning if the first argument is not an array. This differs from the $var[] behaviour where a new array is created.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping to find this in the docs somewhere, but obviously it's a hard thing to search!

Answer (score 1):

When you want to push multiple elements to an array, then you could use `array_push`.

```
array_push($emails, $var1, $var2, $var3, ...);
```

Otherwise, if you only push one elements to an array, just use:

```
$emails[] = $var;
```

which saves you one function call.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does the same thing. Assigning to `$array[]` is equivalent to pushing an element to `$array`.

Also, it looks prettier, so use it ;)